# Django (Python) : Django form is not Displaying

Tags: python, django, forms

I am making my way into Python and Django programming. However, I struggle with displaying a simple form. 
The only element displayed based on the code below is the button, but not (as intended) the entire form. I have already checked the indentation of my code, but have not been able to display the form.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Story (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    audio = models.FileField(default='SOME STRING', upload_to='audio_stories')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('story-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Story


class Story_Creation(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ['title','content','audio']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Story
from .forms import Story_Creation
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    UserPassesTestMixin
    )
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView, 
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)

def Create_Audio_Story(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        s_form = Story_Creation(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if s_form.is_valid():
            s_form.save()
            return redirect('suyuh-home')
    else:
        s_form = Story_Creation()

    context = {
        's_form': s_form,
                }

    return render (request, 'story/story_form.html', context)
```

**story urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    StoryListView,
    StoryDetailView,
    StoryCreateView,
    StoryUpdateView,
    StoryDeleteView,
    UserStoryListView
)

from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', StoryListView.as_view(), name='suyuh-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserStoryListView.as_view(), name='user-stories'),
    path('story/<int:pk>/', StoryDetailView.as_view(), name='story-detail'), #pk pimarykey for stories
    path('story/new/', StoryCreateView.as_view(), name='story-create'),
    path('story/<int:pk>/update/', StoryUpdateView.as_view(), name='story-update'),
    path('story/<int:pk>/delete/', StoryDeleteView.as_view(), name='story-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='suyuh-about'),
]
```

**main urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('story.url')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name='password-reset'),
    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**story_form.html**

```
{% extends "story/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Story</legend>
                {{ s_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create Story</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I do not see my mistake at the moment and therefore do not know how to continue. Thanks a lot for your support. I really appreciate every hint!

Greetings!

Comment: I saw that your template file name is `story_form.html` but you're rendering another file `story/home.html`. Did you check that out?

Comment: I can't tell what you project structure is, but if it's like it seems, the you should update the return statement in the view with: ```return render (request, 'story/story_form.html', context)```

Comment: Many thanks @ToanQuocHo and @revilscano for the answer. I have updated my code to `return render (request, 'story/story_form.html', context)`. Unfortunately the form is still not displayed.

Comment: Please, share the content of the urls.py file with us

Comment: @revliscano Thx is shared!

Comment: I suppose it has something to do with `path('story/new/', StoryCreateView.as_view(), name='story-create'),` This section is handled as a view?

Comment: Oh okay, I think I spotted the mistake. Let me elaborate the answer ;-)

Comment: @revilscano, thx a lot for your support. I solved the mistake `path('story/new/', views.Create_Audio_Story, name='story-create'),` by using the following code. Without your hint to check the urls it would not be possible :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to be updated in your code:

In **main/urls.py** change the parameter passed to the include method, since as I see it, you file in the app `story` is called `urls.py` and not `url.py`

```
path('', include('story.urls'))
```

In **story/urls.py** you are not associating the view called `Create_Audio_Story()` with any path. If you want to have this view shown at /story/new, then you should update the file as follows:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('story/new/', views.Create_Audio_Story, name='story-create'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return render (request, 'story_form.html', context)
```

Try that code instead

Comment: Hi Mohamed, Thanks for the answer i updated the code. But the form is still not displaying. One potential mistake less! Thanks a lot!